# is it safe and/or pythonic to directly overwrite dict entries in the constructor?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm storing some configuration state in a dictionary, where a bunch of separate FFMPEG filters share a common set of parameters, and then we change/override those for each specific filter.  My current code looks like this, and appears to work....

```
    default['common']['fontfile'] = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf'
    default['common']['rate'] = framerate
    default['common']['fontcolor'] = 'yellow'
    default['common']['box'] = 1
    default['common']['y'] = 0       # x and y are offsets from the top left of frame
    default['common']['x'] = 0
```

then I'm just calling another constructor with the ** operator to pull all those common keys/values into my new dict, as well as add some new k/v pairs **and** make some changes to the existing k/v pairs.

In this example I'm changing the values for `'x'` and `'y'` and adding `'start_number' : 0` to the dict:

```
    default['framectr'] = {
        **default['common'], 
        'y' : (vid_h * 0.2), 
        'x' : (vid_w * 0.2),
        'start_number' : 0
        }
```

So far this appears to work, but are there potential side effects here I should be worried about?  I considered just making a `deepcopy()` of the original/common dict and then adding/modifying the entries that way, but at least to my inexperienced eye the constructor call seems cleaner.

Thoughts?

Comment: What constructor are you talking about? Your second example just demonstrates dictionary unpacking inside a [dictionary display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays).

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong term, I meant whatever the correct verb is for "creating a dictionary by passing a bunch of k:v pairs"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantically,

```
default['framectr'] = {
    **default['common'], 
    'y' : (vid_h * 0.2), 
    'x' : (vid_w * 0.2),
    'start_number' : 0
    }
```

is equivalent to

```
default['framectr'] = {
    'fontfile': default['common']['fontfile'],
    'rate': default['common']['rate'],
    'fontcolor': default['common']['fontcolor'],
    'box': default['common']['box'],
    'y': default['common']['y'],
    'x': default['common']['x'],
    'y' : (vid_h * 0.2), 
    'x' : (vid_w * 0.2),
    'start_number' : 0
    }
```

Neither is safer or more dangerous than the other in terms of side effects. Given that you aren't using any mutable values in the definition of `default['common']`, making a deep copy won't buy you anything.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I should have specifically asked if the in-order processing was guaranteed.  I did a smoke test and it worked as expected, but that's not always sufficient.

Comment: The ordering is guaranteed, insofar as your `dict` is ordered. Whether that is true depends on your Python version (in 3.7, it's true in CPython; in 3.8, it's guaranteed by the language), but keep in mind the order is the order in which keys are first added to the `dict`.